# Connect to DRAC

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

This is really getting on my nerves. I installed a Drac 4 card on my Poweredge 2850 server and now no matter what I do, I can not connect to it.

My router assigned a static IP for the card.
I configured the DRAC during the startup (ctrl - d) on the server to use the
ip number the router provided. I can ping the IP without problem. Server administrator sees the card and the IP numbers are correct. And yet when I type in the browser the IP number of the DRAC I get nothing.

I tried using Putty. I type the IP number - get few warning messages if I want to proceed with the connection - I proceed ---
Then I get the login prompt.
For user I type 'root' and tried the default 'calvin' password. No luck.
Using server administrator I created another user. Repeated the procedure ... but on password enter I get access denied.
Tried everything but all failed.
I really dont know what else to do. I miss the ability to wake my server if its off. Cant use WOL because there is no such option in BIOS. I dont get any option for configuring the NIC's.
So, for the love of god, can someone tell me what exactly must I do so I can reach the DRAC?
I cant even use port forwarding to it because the 443 port does not work. And there is no way I can configure the DRAC port as there is no such option.

I cant even reach DRAC locally let alone from the internet. Why every password I type fails ? Firewall is off. I really dont know what else to do. Please help.

edit:
when I try and connect with putty to : 192.168.178.40 port 22
I get first :

[image]

Clicking Yes takes me to :

[image]

It then refuses every password I type in.

With the browser (firefox) I get :

[image]

Comment: `My router assigned a static IP for the card. I configured the DRAC during the startup (ctrl - d) on the server to use the ip number the router provided` - That doesn't quite make sense. If the router assigned an ip address to the DRAC (via DHCP) why would you have to manually configure the ip address? Those two things are in opposition to each other.

Comment: Have you installed the latest firmware on the DRAC? Have you specifically enabled SSH? Have you tried RACADM? Do you have any other systems on your network that would respond to SSH? Maybe you have the IP addresses in conflict, or mixed up and you are actually SSHing in to a different system than you think, and that is why the web interface also doesn't work. Did you configure which network port the DRAC will use in system setup?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I was on holiday. N, I did not install latest firmware for drac because I can not get into DRAC setup. Enabled SSH ? And where do you do that for DRAC? I have no IP conflict because DHCP is handled by router and it assignes static IP for my drac (does not change it). I can not configure port because I can not reach drac setup.

Comment: @joeqwerty I set it up manually just in case.Otherwise numbers are the same. Its just I set up my router so it always assigns the same IP to my drac.I can ping the drac but I can not get into its settings or through my browser.

Comment: iDRAC 4 is awful old, it came out 2005. Try using an older version of a web browser, that still supports the old encryption ciphers that have been removed from all modern browsers. And by "old" I mean really old ... 2005 was the time of FireFox 1.0 and 1.5. Additionally, you'll need a similar old version of Java (the manual states Java 1.4).

Comment: And you should really consider replacing such an old machine. By now it belongs into a museum™.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider This server is really good. Like a workhorse. I really like it. It basically serves all my needs so I really have no desire to replace it.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider I tried your suggestion and tried with an older browser. Firefox1. I did manage to show up login page however it refuses all my usernames and passwords.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a factory reset of iDRAC.

Comment: tried with old browsers but they seem not to accept username and password.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider How do you reset the IDrac to factory settings ?